# How do I set the accelerator for a key within an Action?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I am trying to consolidate most of my menus in 2 similar applications that share a lot of classes. Part of this is I am trying to move anything I can into actions. The issue I am running into is I want the same accelerators for the menu items. Is there a way I can set this in the action so that I don't have to duplicate my code for setting the accelerator?

```
package com.protocase.viewer.actions;

import com.protocase.viewer.DesignerApplication;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.MNEMONIC_KEY;
import static javax.swing.Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION;


/**
 *
 * @author davidh
 */
public class NewEnclosureAction extends AbstractAction{

    private DesignerApplication app;

    public NewEnclosureAction(DesignerApplication app) {
        super();
        this.app = app;
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "New");
        putValue(AbstractAction.NAME, "New");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_N);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       app.OnNew();
    }

}
```

..........

```
    JMenuItem newMit = new JMenuItem(new NewEnclosureAction(this));
    newMit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    newMit.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("New Enclosure from template");
    fileMenu.add(newMit);
```

..........

I am looking to move the setAccelerator calls to within my action class.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: 1) Use [`Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#ACCELERATOR_KEY) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I would say this is a pretty simple example. I showed what my action class looks like and where I called it.

Comment: 'Simple' is not any single part of 'SSCCE'.  Please *read* the link.

Comment: Agreeable. I will reference this next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a value for accelerator keys like for the short description, that would, for you case, be written like this :

```
    putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
```

If you use Eclipse as IDE, it should tell you the available keys when typing `putValue` and hitting the auto-complete shortcut.